# Existence of a countable linear combination with positive coefficients

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, locally-convex-spaces

Consider a (Hausdorff and complete) locally convex topological vector space $V$ and a countable subset $(v_k)_{k=1}^\infty \subset V$ of non-zero vectors.

> $(*)$ Under what conditions on this subset are we guaranteed the existence of a sequence of positive real numbers $(\alpha_k)_{k=1}^\infty$, such that the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k v_k$ converges (that is, the sequence of its partial sums) converges to a vector $v \in V$?

The positivity of the coefficients, $\alpha_k > 0$ for each $k$, is the crucial aspect of the question.

On the one hand, if $V$ is a Banach space, the answer is always Yes. We can always choose $\alpha_k = c_k / \|v_k\|$, where $(c_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ is any summable sequence of positive numbers.

On the other hand, consider the space $c_{00}$ of finite sequences of real numbers, turned into a complete locally convex space in the usual way. The the subset $(v_k)_{k=1}^\infty$, where the $v_k$ is the sequence that is zero everywhere except the $k$-th place, is an example for which such a sequence of $(\alpha_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ does not exist. This is clear because here a necessary and sufficient condition for the convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k v_k$ is that only finitely many $\alpha_k$ are non-zero.

So maybe I could ask the question in a slightly different way. Is there a well-studied (joint?) property of the space $V$ and the subset $(v_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ that is sufficient (hopefully also necessary) for the answer to $(*)$ to be Yes? I was hoping that the answer would be related to one of the standard theorems of functional analysis, but I haven't recognized the right one yet.

Comment: I know a couple of "usual" ways to make $c_{00}$ into a locally convex space, but unless I have got my definitions completely wrong, they aren't complete...

Comment: @NateEldredge: How about the weak* topology on the dual to the Fréchet space of all sequences?

Comment: @IgorKhavkine: No, the weak-$*$ topology is not complete, since $c_{00}$ is not the algebraic dual of $s$. You probably mean the locally convex direct sum topology $c_{00} \cong \bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{R}$, which is complete since each of the summands is complete. This is the finest locally convex topology on $c_{00}$. Furthermore, it follows from Köthe, §22.5.(4) that this coincides with both the strong and the Mackey topology. (See also Köthe's section on sequence spaces, §30.2.)

Comment: @J.vanDobbendeBruyn  You're right. That is how I was thinking about it. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a partial answer, note the following necessary (and often sufficient) criteria.

Let $E$ be a (real or complex) topological vector space. Let us say that a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ in $E$ *can be made summable/bounded/to converge to zero* if there is a sequence $\{\alpha_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ of strictly positive real scalars such that $\{\alpha_n x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is summable/bounded/converges to zero.

> **Proposition.** *Consider the following statements:*
>
> *$\text{(a)}$. $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ can be made summable;*
>
> *$\text{(b)}$. $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ can be made to converge to zero;*
>
> *$\text{(c)}$. $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ can be made bounded.*
>
> *In every topological vector space $E$ one has*
>   $$\text{(a)} \Longrightarrow \text{(b)} \Longleftrightarrow \text{(c)}.$$
>   *If $E$ is locally convex and sequentially complete, then*
>   $$\text{(a)} \Longleftrightarrow \text{(b)} \Longleftrightarrow \text{(c)}. $$
>
> *Proof.* $\text{(a)} \Longrightarrow \text{(b)}$. Suppose that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k x_k$ converges to $y \in E$. Let $s_n := \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k x_k$ denote the $n$-th partial sum. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} s_{n+1} = y$, so by continuity of addition
>   $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \alpha_{n+1} x_{n+1} = \lim_{n\to\infty} s_{n+1} - s_n = y - y = 0. $$
>
> $\text{(b)} \Longrightarrow \text{(c)}$. [Every convergent sequence is bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1471005/).
>
> $\text{(c)} \Longrightarrow \text{(b)}$. If $\{\alpha_n x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is bounded, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} \alpha_n \beta_n x_n = 0$ for every sequence $\{\beta_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ of scalars converging to zero (see e.g. Rudin, Theorem 1.30).
>
> Assume now that $E$ is locally convex and sequentially complete. $\text{(b)} \Longrightarrow \text{(a)}$. Suppose that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \alpha_n x_n = 0$. Define $s_n := \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\alpha_k}{2^k} x_k$. Use local convexity to prove that $\{s_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is Cauchy, and use sequential completeness to conclude that the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\alpha_k}{2^k} x_k$ converges. $\Box$

Some remarks:

1. Each of the properties $\text{(a)}$, $\text{(b)}$ and $\text{(c)}$ carries over to all weaker (i.e. coarser) topologies, even those with different dual spaces. Interestingly, in locally convex spaces, property $\text{(c)}$ only depends on the dual pair.
2. If the topology of $E$ is given by a metric $d$, then every sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ satisfies $\text{(b)}$. To prove this, note that for every $z \in E$ we have $\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{1}{k}z = 0$ (by continuity of scalar multiplication). Equivalently: for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists some $K_\varepsilon \in \mathbb{N}_1$ so that $d(0,\frac{1}{k} z) < \varepsilon$ for all $k \geq K_\varepsilon$. Using this, we choose a sequence $\{\alpha_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ of strictly positive real scalars so that $d(0,\alpha_n x_n) < \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}_1$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty} \alpha_n x_n = 0$.
3. The answer of Robert Israel follows from the previous remark and the Proposition.
4. There are also non-metrizable tvs where every sequence satisfies $\text{(b)}$ (take a metrizable space and pass to a weaker topology). Likewise, there exist non-Fréchet tvs where every sequence satisfies $\text{(a)}$. Interesting [follow-up question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/355466/120251): if every sequence satisfies $\text{(b)}$ (resp. $\text{(a)}$), then is there necessarily a finer topology which is metrizable (resp. Fréchet)?

Comment: Great answer, thanks! And the proof is of course the same if completeness is weakened to sequential completeness. I see now that my example sequence in $c_{00}$ cannot even be made bounded, because every bounded subset of $c_{00}$ must be finite dimensional (Köthe §18.5(4)). This is a useful enough criterion that I'll accept.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine: Thanks for the suggestion — I changed it to sequential completeness (and added some additional remarks). I think you provided the perfect example, illustrating exactly what can go wrong, even in the strong dual of a separable Fréchet space. Furthermore, I concur with your retrospective analysis of the example — I think the boundedness condition might be even easier to see than the convergence.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine thanks for looking out, but I respectfully disagree with your latest edit. ;-) Maybe my argument could be clearer, but the idea is to fix $n$ and let $k$ go to infinity. The metric provides a way to choose $\alpha_n$ separately for each $n$, but still end up with a convergent sequence $\{\alpha_n x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$. (Compare with the $\max\{ \lVert \upsilon_j\rVert_k \, : \, k \leq j\}$ construction from Robert Israel's answer — I guess I could do something similar using the concept of F-norms, but the current approach seems easier.)

Comment: Update: added a few extra words to make the aforementioned argument clearer.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I got confused by the notation. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

It's true in a Fréchet space.  If $\|\cdot\|_k$, $k = 0,1,2,\ldots$, is a family
of seminorms that induces the topology, choose $\alpha_j = c_j/\max\{\| v_j \|_k : k \le j\}$ for a summable sequence of positive numbers $c_j$.